# Reading multiple text files and replacing a certain type of string in each of them using a batch file

Tags: string, batch-file, replace

I need to read all the text files from a directory and then replace a certain type of string (that comes in a line having 'volumelabel') with another (replacewith) in each of them. Following is the code snippet:

```
for /r %%g in (*.txt) do (
 set filename=%%~nxg
 for /F "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%i in ('findstr "volumelabel" !filename!') do (
  set tobereplaced=%%i
 )
 echo !filename! has !tobereplaced! to be replaced by %replacewith%
 for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (!filename!) do (
  set str=%%a
  set str=!str:!tobereplaced!=%replacewith%!
  echo !str!>>new!filename!
 )
)
```

Now the problem I am facing is it prints only `tobereplaced` (literally) in every line of the new files when

```
set str=!str:!tobereplaced!=%replacewith%!
echo !str!>>new!filename!
```

is used and prints `tobereplaced=replacewith` (values) when

```
set str=%str:!tobereplaced!=%replacewith%%
echo !str!>>new!filename!
```

is used. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The least convoluted solution (in my humble opinion) is to use a subroutine to `set str`.  Going more than one level deep of delayed expansion tends to cause severe brain hurt.  Oh, you could probably fix your `set str` line by doing something like

```
call call call set str=%%%%str:%%tobereplaced%%=%replacewith%%%%%
```

...or similar.  See what I mean about brain hurt?  It's hard to follow the recursion.

So here's my suggestion for a solution.  I also fixed another potential problem or two while I was at it.  Since you're doing a recursive search for *.txt, I made the `for` loops able to work with whatever text files they find within subdirectories.  I haven't tested this, so let me know if you get any grotesque errors.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set replacewith=whatever

for /r %%g in (*.txt) do (
    set newfile=%%~dpng.new%%~xg
    for /F "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%i in ('findstr "volumelabel" "%%g"') do (
        set "tobereplaced=%%i"
        echo %%~nxg has !tobereplaced! to be replaced by %replacewith%

        rem combining your for loops this way makes the second only fire if the first is true
        rem using "findstr /n" in your for loop preserves blank lines
        for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "%%g"') do (

            rem ...but you have to strip off the line numbers
            set "str=%%a" && set "str=!str:*:=!"

            rem "call :repl" to work around the delayed expansion conundrum
            call :repl "!str!" "!tobereplaced!" "%replacewith%" str
            echo !str!>>!newfile!
        )
    )
)
goto :EOF

:repl <line> <find> <replace> <var>
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "line=%~1"
set "line=!line:%~2=%~3!"
set "%4=%line%"
goto :EOF
```

Caveat: If your text file contains exclamation marks, equal signs or carats, they might not make it into textfile.new.txt.

---

For what it's worth, if I were in your position, instead of using a batch file I would probably use [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) (the binaries should be all you need).  You wouldn't even need a script.  You could do it as a one liner like this:

```
for /r %I in (*.txt) do sed -r "s/volumelabel/replacement/ig" "%I" > "%~dpnI.new%~xI"
```

By the way, see the last couple of pages of `help for` for an explanation of the `%~dpnI` sort of notation.

Comment: Can you please test it yourself? I tested and it din't work. And it really causes brain-hurt as I dint understand anything out of it! :(

Comment: @ABC - This is, as they say, your party.  I have no idea whether the logic I copied from your script example is as it should be, whether `volumelabel` is indeed the third token in the text files, for instance.  Can you pastebin an example text file this script is supposed to be able to modify?  I'm also adding another suggestion to my main answer.